# Functional programming database models

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

How to work with db models in functional programming (js for example).
If i have regular orm the code will be similar to:

```
let users = await usersRepo.where({active: 1})
    .limit(10)
    .orderBy('dateCreated, 'asc')
    .get()

// activate the users
let mails = []
for(let u of users) {
    mails.push(u.activate());
}
```

In functional programming:

```
 let users = users.get(db, {where: {active: 1}, order: 'dateadded'})
 for(u of users){
     usersFn.activate(db, u)
 }
```

I have to pass db and each instance it causes confusion because i have to pass many arguments(db for example) since no state are being pass to the constructors.

Is there more convenient way because the OOP variant is way more pretty.
I want to use functional programming but not to sacrifice code beauty.
This is OOP:

```
class User {
    constructor(db) {
        this.db = db
    }
    get(constraints) {

    }
}
let users = new User(db)
let result = users.get({where: {active: 1}, order: 'date'})
```

This is fp with higher order function:

```
const bindUsersGet = (db) => {
    return (constraints) => {
        // db is available here
        // constraints as well
    }
}
let boundUserGet = bindUsersGet(db)
let result = boundUserGet({ where: { active: 1 }, order: 'dateadded' })
```

I dont see how fp with higher order function is better than OOP variant.
It is the same except the syntax? What's so special about it?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of magic should functional programming unfold for this code snippet in your opinion? The differences emerge in the long run.

Comment: What is the long run?
The difference is only syntax.
Can you send real world details what will be the long run advantage using higher order snippet vs OOP snippet?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the concept of a [higher order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) to generate a "bound" users that already knows the DB instance. Some rough code:

```
const bindUsersGet = (db) => {
    return (constraints) => {
        // db is available here
        // constraints as well
    }
}


let boundUserGet = bindUsersGet(db)
let result = boundUserGet({ where: { active: 1 }, order: 'dateadded' })
```

This is an example for a single function, but you can obviously also return an object with multiple functions all having access to the `db` given to the "outer" function.

Comment: Yes i thought of this but this is basically OOP. You store db and then use it. This is OOP with fp clothes for me.
class user {
    constructor(db){...}
    get(constraints(){...}
}
I dont see the difference except in syntax.

Also if i need to pass another argument like db it will be similar to OOP class.

Comment: You are not wrong, but conceptually it's something different and it works differently in detail. There are no typical OOP concepts like inheritance here for example. Also this works by scoping and not using class members.

Comment: Yes i understand this. I dont say that it is bad, i just want to know what are the advantages agains OOP. You can make classes without inheritance also so if i exclude syntax it's 1:1. If anyone give some arguments why fp is better in this case.